# ARC Issue: No Visible @interface Declares the Selector

Tags: iphone, objective-c, selector

I have an issue with this function. Its Objective-C and deployed on iPhone.

```
-(UIImage *)addCircle:(UIImage *)img radius:(CGFloat)radius latCon:(CGFloat)lat lonCon:(CGFloat)lon;
```

I have declared in .h as:

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate> {
     CLLocationManager *locationManager;

}

-(UIImage *)addCircle:(UIImage *)img radius:(CGFloat)radius latCon:(CGFloat)lat lonCon:(CGFloat)lon;

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

@end
```

And in called in the corresponding .m as:

```
[self addCircle:(mapImage) influence:(70) latCon:(320) lonCon:(320)];
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep: `influence` is not the same as `radius`.